# No appendonly.aof file is created when I input some command in redis-cli

Tags: redis

I have my config file of Redis like this:

Working directory where `dump.rdb` and `appendonly.aof` are output:

```
dir /var/redis/6379
```

I have set `appendonly` to yes like this:

```
appendonly yes
```

I also set the syn:

```
appendfsync everysec
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
```

I know something will be added to appendonly.aof everytime I type command in redis-cli.But when I input some command which modifies the key in redis-cli, no appendonly.aof file is created in the directory `/var/redis/6379`.

PS: I have not had an `appendonly.aof` file in `/var/redis/6379` before.

----update at 2014/10/7 23:30---

I have a dump.rdb file in /var/redis/6379, and dump.rdb will be updated everytime I execute `shutdown` in redis-cli.

User I run the redis-server is john,and the permission of /var/redis/6379 is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 john john 4096 Oct  7 23:28 6379/
```

So, the permission is all right.

Comment: Is there a `dump.rdb` file in `/var/redis/6379/`? I just want to rule out the possibility that the user running `redis-server` doesn't have permission to write to `/var/redis/6379`.

Answer (score -1):

When you get the redis-server started,you're supposed to follow the "/your exact dir/redis.conf" to make the modify to redis.conf work.If not,the redis-server would use the default configure(but not the redis.conf),where appendonly option is set to no. As a result,no appendonly.aof created at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is what solved the problem for *me* (it may not for you).
I didn't post this answer for the original poster, because he surely has already solved his problem as he asked the question around 3.5 years ago.
This is for anybody else that may have the same problem (such as I did).

**NOTE:** These instructions will be for Windows although I'm sure that they could just as easily be translated to any other Operating System.
If anyone would like me to add in additional instructions for other Operating Systems, let me know in a comment; I'll do my best to edit it as needed.

If it happens to solve anybody's problem, then please leave an up-vote.

For anybody reading this, I will assume that you have already configured the Redis config file (called "*redis.windows.conf*" on Windows) **before** you follow this guide.
If somebody would like instructions on how to configure the Redis config file, then let me know with a comment; I can edit it into the guide.

**(1. Insure that the Redis service has been stopped:**

**(A. Method 1 - Using the Windows Services manager (NOTE: this method is easier and shorter than Method 2, but I believe that Redis does NOT perform a save before it shuts down with this method whereas it can with Method 2):**

- Open the Windows Services manager. The easiest way to do this is to simply search for "Services" in the Windows search bar:

[image]

- Scroll down the list until you find the Redis service.
  If the "Status" field is empty, then the service is *not* running (if you want to be sure that this information is still current, use the "Refresh" option in the "Action" menu).
  However, if the status field says "Started", then the service is running.
  Right-click on the service (or select the service then open the "Action" menu), and select the "Stop" option:

[image]

**(B. Method 2 - Using the Redis CLI (Command Line Interface):**

- Open the Windows Command Prompt (i.e. "CMD.exe"; The easiest way is to simply search "CMD" in the Windows search bar):

[image]

- Navigate to the home directory of Redis (this is the place where you
  installed Redis at; mine was at "C:/Program Files/Redis") by typing:
  "cd **path to the Redis home directory**" into the command prompt
  and pressing "Enter":

[image]

- Type "redis-cli" and press "Enter". If nothing happens, then it most likely means that the Redis service is already stopped.  If this is the case then simply press "ctr+C" to back out.
  However, if the service is running then this (or something like to it) should show up:

[image]

I think the numbers *may* be different for *some* people, but I can't say for sure.
I'm pretty sure that this number consists of the IP address and a port number that your database is running under.

For **most** people it will probably look like this, but if you changed the default port number or something akin to that, it will not be the same as depicted in the picture.

- Type [image: "SHUTDOWN SAVE"] or [image: "SHUTDOWN NOSAVE"] based upon whether or not you want Redis to do one final save before it shuts down and press "Enter".  The IP address/port combo should now read as "not connected":

[image]

**(2. Insure that the Redis config file (again, named "redis.windows.conf" on Windows) has been properly configured and has been SAVED. Also make sure that the file is in the Redis home directory;**

**(3. Restart the Redis service (but NOT through the Windows Services manager):**

- Navigate to the Redis home directory with a Command Prompt (refer to Method 2 of Step 1 for instructions of how to do this).
  Now type "redis-server **name of Redis config file**" and press "Enter":

[image]

- Something like this should be displayed:

[image]

- There should now be an "appendonly.aof" (or whatever you configured the name to be) file in your Redis home directory (at least there was for me).
  If it isn't there, you could try executing one of the basic Redis commands to see if it will save that command and thereby create the file.

I hope this helps anybody else that may stumble upon this guide.